# Cannot install magit - unavailable package

Tags: emacs, magit

I've just copied my `.emacs` file into a new freshly installed Ubuntu 16.04 and Emacs installed through `apt`. Anyway `magit` is the only package that it wasn't able to install. It says:

```
Error (use-package): Failed to install magit: Package `emacs-25.1' is unavailable
```

My Emacs version is `24.5.1` and my git version is `2.7.4`. I also tried to run `M-x package-refresh-contents` and manually install `magit` using `package-install`. But the error is still the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Magit [dropped](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/magit/magit/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.13.0.txt) support for Emacs 24.  Either:

- upgrade Emacs
- use melpa-stable for magit ("pinning")
- install an older version of magit manually